# Node js memory usage with clusters

Tags: node.js, memory

I have an application written in Node using many features such as the cluster module.

I need to know the memory usage of my app on a specific time, what I am thinking of is looping through the active workers and sum the output of all of them but I don't know if the output value will be correct. any one here can help me please?

In fact I can't seem also to know the true meanings of the three "rss","heapTotal","heapUsed" mean.. I googled it and what I found is what important to monitor is "heapTotal" & "heapUsed", is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

**RSS** is the [resident set size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size), the portion of the process's memory held in RAM (as opposed to the swap space or the part held in the filesystem).

The **heap** is the portion of memory from which newly allocated objects will come from (think of `malloc` in C, or `new` in JavaScript).

Good [Tutorial](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-heap-profiling-tip/)

More about heap [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management).

Happy Helping!